# solve for second order linear differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, fundamental-solution

I got the sum of A is 0? There is no solution to this? Can someone please help. Thanks!

$$y''-4y'+4y=-6e^{2t}$$

Comment: Have you noticed the repeated root ... if you show your working so far it should be simple to point out your mistake.

Comment: What did you get for your general solution to the homogeneous case and what are you going to use for your trial solution ... just be careful you don't choose $y=Ae^2t$ because it should be in your GS

Comment: The good Dr Graubner has given you all you need ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what you mean by "sum of A".  There is no "A" in the problem.  Do you mean that you are looking for a "particular solution" of the form $Ae^{2t}$?  If so you should NOT be getting A= 0- you should not be getting anything at all for A!  Setting $y= Ae^{2t}$, $y'= 2Ae^{2t}$ and $y''= 4Ae^{2t}$ so that $y''- 4y+ 4= 4Ae^{2t}- 8Ae^{2t}+ 4Ae^{2t}= 0$ no matter what A is.

The "double root" that Bruce refers to is the double root of the characteristic equation: the associated homogeneous differential equation, y''- 4y'+ 4y= 0, has characteristic equation $r^2- 4r+ 4= (r- 2)^2= 0$ which has the double root r= 2.  The general solution to the associated homogeneous equation is $y(t)= C_1e^{2t}+ C_2te^{2t}$.  You need to look for a specific solution of the form $y(t)= At^2e^{2t}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: make for the particular solution the ansatz

$$y_p=Ae^{2t}t^2$$

Comment: Thank you it makes sense now!

Answer (score 0):

Try this as particular solution
$$y_p=At^2e^{2t}$$

---

**Another solution**
$$y''-4y'+4y=-6e^{2t}$$
Rewriting the differential equation
$$(y''-2y')-2(y'-2y)=-6e^{2t}$$
$$(y'e^{-2t})'-2(ye^{-2t})'=-6$$
Integrate
$$y'e^{-2t}-2ye^{-2t}=-6t+K_1$$
$$(ye^{-2t})'=-6t+K_1$$
Integrate again
$$ye^{-2t}=-3t^2+K_1t+K_2$$
Finally we get, 
$$\boxed{y(t)=e^{2t}(-3t^2+K_1t+K_2)}$$

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: yw @linda ..............